# show gps latitude and longitude on a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, latitude-longitude

I am working on gps web app, where I need to get lat and longitude of a user to a hiddenfield on a page load or button click. By using these I can retrieve user required information from my database.

Currently I could able to retrieve gps coordinates by javascript on page load, could some one tell me how to get those lat and long to a hiddenfiled or label in c#.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( $("input#fooBox").val() ); // alert default value
$("input#fooBox").val("end test"); // change value
alert( $("input#fooBox").val() ); // alert new value

<input type="hidden" id="fooBox" value="hello world" />
```